# Odiya Language Support In Apache FOP

Tags: truetype, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP 1.1 and kalinga.ttf font for Odiya Language(an indian language).
I got following error.
[image]

Please do the needful if there is any alternative or solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As information read from this page,there is scope for Future development of Oriya Language
**Till date it is not supporting much oriya lymphs.**
1. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/complexscripts.html
2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2286